# What is compressor.io doing to the images?

Tags: image, image-processing

I wonder sites and apps like http://compressor.io how compress image, sometimes more than 50% decrease in size, that the changes in compressed image is not visible with eye? What really is changed and removed and made the image smaller? What if I print the new image, would be same as the original picture in quality?

Comment: to get a general idea of how almost all lossy compression algorithms work,consider dct transform.it converts image from spatial to frequency domain,upper left corner of the transformed data represent low frequencies and lower right represent high frequencies.it turns out that zeroing out the coefficients in the lower right corner made little difference(to our eyes)when the modified frequencies are transformed back into spatial domain.this is where compression comes in,the more you can zero out without our eyes spotting anything, more compression you can get due to huffman coding of frequencies

Comment: you can refer to documents online such as this(http://www.lokminglui.com/dct.pdf) for more indepth info. you can also use programs such as this (http://www.jcrystal.com/products/ftlse/) to understand "hands-on" the effect of zeroing out different frequencies bands. the program does fft but the principles are the same.now how to achieve optimal compression? a naive method is to calculate psnr or ssim beore and after image and keep reducing the coefficients while ssim is still above a set threshold. tools such as jpgcrush and algos such as trellis quantization achieve this task better